# get the name of the file which user given when downloading image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video-capture

I am using React,Basically i need to download the image and access the name of the image, to store the names in array to access the image later.The downloading part is working fine.But i need to get the user given file name of the image.

This is my download function,

```
download(){
    var download = document.getElementById("download");
    var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png")
                .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    var filename = download.setAttribute("href", image);
   }
```

this is my render method,

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
       <WebCamPicture landmarkPicture={this.landmarkWebCamPicture} /><br/>
        <canvas id="canvas" ref={this.canvasPicWebCam} width={350} height={350} /><br/>
        <a id="download"  download="image.png"><button type="button" onClick= 
          {this.download}>Download</button></a>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the image file name of the file you are downloading?

Comment: yes.i get the solution by using prompt in the download attribute in anchor tag.